# How to refresh/redraw only the supplementary views in a uicollectionview?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

Is it possible to refresh or redraw only the supplementary views in a UICollectionView? I have a scenario where I will be updating each section with insert/delete of rows, based on which I need to update the section header or the so-called supplementary views (it has a UI element whose visibility is dependant on the no of items in that section). So is there any way to update the supplementary views of a UICollectionView without needing to updating anything else?

Also, if the specific section doesnt contain any data I need to make the size of the supplementary view as empty?

SupplementaryView:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Foundation;
using IpcCommon;
using IpcCommon.Enumerations;
using IpcCommon.Model;
using ObjCRuntime;
using UIKit;

namespace ipc_offline_app.iOS.Portal.CustomCells.Dashboard.Redesign
{
    public partial class DashboardHeader : UICollectionReusableView
    {
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("DashboardHeader");
        public static readonly UINib Nib;

        private DashCategories _dashboardCategory;
        private bool _hideViewAll;
        private IShelfItemClickListener _listener;
        private string _title;

        static DashboardHeader()
        {
            Nib = UINib.FromName("DashboardHeader", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        }

        protected DashboardHeader(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public static DashboardHeader CreateCell()
        {
            var array = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("DashboardHeader", null, null);
            var cell = Runtime.GetNSObject<DashboardHeader>(array.ValueAt(0));
            return cell;
        }

        public void PopulateCell(string title, IShelfItemClickListener listener, bool hideViewAll, DashCategories category = DashCategories.NONE)
        {
            _title = title;
            _dashboardCategory = category;
            _listener = listener;
            ViewAllButton.Hidden = hideViewAll;
            _hideViewAll = hideViewAll;
            TitleButton.SetTitle(_title, UIControlState.Normal);
            UpdateViewAllVisibility();
        }

        [Export("awakeFromNib")]
        public new void AwakeFromNib()
        {
            ViewAllButton.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;
            ViewAllButton.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            ViewAllButton.Layer.BorderColor = Utils.ColorFromHex(Colors.SILVER).CGColor;
        }

        partial void OpenSection(NSObject sender)
        {
            if (_listener != null && _dashboardCategory != DashCategories.NONE)
                _listener.OnShelfItemClicked(_dashboardCategory, IpcCommon.Constants.VIEW_TYPE_GALLERY);
        }

        public void UpdateViewAllVisibility(Dictionary<DashCategories, List<Assignment>> filteredAssignments = null)
        {
            if (filteredAssignments != null && filteredAssignments[_dashboardCategory].Count > IpcCommon.Constants.MAX_SECTION_ITEMS)
                _hideViewAll = false;
            ViewAllButton.Hidden = _hideViewAll;
            NSLayoutConstraint trailingConstraint;
            if (_hideViewAll)
                trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(TitleButton, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, ViewAllButton, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1, 0);
            else
                trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(TitleButton, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, ViewAllButton, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1, -10);
            AddConstraint(trailingConstraint);
            LayoutIfNeeded();
            LayoutSubviews();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything like CollectionView.ReloadItems for reloading supplementaryview ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can get a reference to each visible supplementary view of that section which you insert/delete data.

I don't see your code, you should know the `indexPath` of `section` which you are inserting/deleting data.

For example:

```
   // indexP here is an example
   NSIndexPath indexP = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0,0);         
   Header supplementaryView = CollectionView.GetSupplementaryView(myelementkind, indexP) as Header;

   //perform your own action here    
   supplementaryView.checkvisibility();
```

Comment: Hi I have updated the question. The thing is that data can added or removed from section and if there are no data in a section at a scenario we need to hide the section header itself ie header reference size should be empty and later if we add data it should be again shown

Comment: @MidhunKumar You should override this method [getreferencesizeforheader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout.getreferencesizeforheader) to change header's height to 0 to hide header.

Comment: I had already overridden that method. The thing is after when the api brings new data and inserts additional rows into or say remove rows how will I initiate a call to the getreferencesizeforheader method ?

Comment: UICollectionvView.CollectionViewLayout.InvalidateLayout(); makes sure getreferencesizeforheader gets called. But it wont make the view gets redrawn again. Maybe for that like you suggested I might have to have myown method

Comment: Tried calling a different method as well but no effect. Updated the class in question. 
Similar to ReloadItem is there anything we can call to update a siupplementaryView?

Comment: @MidhunKumar  You should call reload section to redraw the view. You can try my suggestion and let me know if it works.